# find the top most div by checking z-index using jquery

Tags: jquery, z-index

I need to find top most div by checking z-index:

```
<div>
<div id="box_1">some image</div>
<div id="box_444">some image</div>
<div id="box_555">some image</div>
<div id="box_888">some image</div>
<div id="box_999">some image</div>
</div>
```

the best way I can explain is like shuffling a deck of images in the dark without knowing which image is on top. Basically I need to check which div has the highest z-index and identify by the div's id.

Can any jquery expert help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the z-index set using a particular `class`, or is it set in the `style` attribute (in-line CSS)?

Comment: So what you really want is an algorithm for finding the max number in a set? Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 3):

> Basically I need to check which div has the highest z-index and identify by the div's id

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var allDivs = $('div div');
var topZindex = 0;
var topDivId;
allDivs.each(function(){
    var currentZindex = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'), 10);
    if(currentZindex > topZindex) {
        topZindex = currentZindex;
        topDivId = this.id;
    }
});

console.log(topDivId);
console.log(topZindex);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emLcY/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var greatest = 0;
var greatestDiv;

$('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('z-index') > greatest){
        greatest = $(this).css('z-index');
        greatestDiv = $(this).attr('id');
    }
})

console.log(greatest);
console.log(greatestDiv);
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljptw/5/) will get you there:

```
$(function(){
    var highest = -1, el = null;
    $('div[id^="box"]').each(function(){

        var z = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'), 10);

        if (z > highest) { 
            el = this;
            highest = z;                    
        }
    });

    console.log('the highest is:', el)
});​
```

Comment: Since your code already uses jQuery, why not use `$(this).css('z-index')`? That would get the computed `z-index` value even if it's not defined as an inline style.

Comment: From my tests it did not get the right css z-index, and accessing the property directly will reduce overhead. The `css` wrapper is handy sometimes.

Comment: I've looked at the fiddle. Your computed values are indeed `auto`, because your divs are not positioned. `z-index` can only be applied to positioned elements. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljptw/4/).

Comment: This is true, making `css` a much better candidate. Hopefully these comments will help someone else out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    var $divs = $('div > div');   
    var maxId = '';
    var max = 0;

    $.each($divs, function(i){
       var a = $($divs[i]).css('z-index');
        console.log(a);
        if(parseInt(a) > parseInt(max)){
           max = a;
           maxId = $(this).attr('id');
        }
    });    
    alert(maxId);
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8FgKZ/3/)

```
$.fn.topmost = function () {
    var positionedDivs = this.filter( function() {
        return !isNaN( parseInt( $(this).css("z-index"), 10 ) );
    });
    var topElem = positionedDivs.first();

    positionedDivs.each( function() {
        if ( $(this).css('z-index') > +topElem.css("z-index") ) {
            topElem = $(this);
        }
    });

    return topElem.get(0) || this.get(0);
};

$(function() {
    var topDiv = $('div > div').topmost();
    console.log( topDiv.id )
});​
```